# combine multiple rows/ columns into single row SQL ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a user table, a role table that holds roleID and name, and a userrole table that has roleID and userID. Users can have multiple roles, so there could be multiple records returned for my select query. Is there a way that I can combine each roleID into a single row with a new column added for the additional roleID if it exists, either through a sql proc or in VB?  I have a gridview that I will use for role management, it has 3 columns for roles, each with a checkbox that allows adding or deleting a role.

Comment: You should separate display logic from database schema. retrieve your data "as is" then recreate new data source object (eg. new DataTable)

Answer (score 4):

Don't store multiple items in a single database column; you're violating first normal form, which is not good database design.

In your case, you could create a View that aggregates your multiple roles into a single "column" (comma delimited), and then base your gridview's datasource on the new View, instead of the base table.

You could do the same thing through a stored procedure.

Comment: I actually did not want to delimit them into a single column, rather add an additional column onto the row only if the user has multiple roles. I do see your point and I want to keep it normalized.

Comment: A view or a stored proc would still probably be your solution Bob